# -kernel option like in QEMU for BOCHS

Tags: kernel, bootloader, qemu, bochs

I am working on creating my own kernel using C/Asm. I have always used QEMU as my emulator mainly because I can specify `-kernel` and it boots the kernel directly without a boot loader. I wish to switch to BOCHS for emulation and I was wondering if there was a similar option to avoid a boot loader and just boot the `kernel.bin`. Thanks!